# how to add item hidden in list to add in spinner when items in spinner get of json

Tags: android, json, xml

how to add item hidden in list to add in spinner when items in spinner get of json  i used Spinner and tried AppCompatSpinner and android:prompt="@string/filter" 
but all this not working

See the attached images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post your code as text, not as an image?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Without it, how do you expect to us to help you? Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).